# Why does Parse change my ID to a duplicate of objectId?

Tags: parse-platform

I have imported an existing table from my DB to parse yet the col that i had labeled id and was numbered 1,2,3...etc is now a duplicate of Parse's auto generated objectId.

How do I prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: show how you did this import and a sample of the source and result data

Comment: I Imported with CSV as per the instructions. Example below: "id","username","email","password","salt"
1,"Demo Dave","demo@demo.com","xxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx"